# Update different column in different rows using a single query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been wanting to update column 'first name' for row 1 and column 'dept_id' for row 2 in a single query. Can it be done? The one in ** is the one i want to update.

```
last_name     first_name       dept_id
jerry            tom            **50**
snow           **black**          20


UPDATE EMP2_5
SET dept_id = '50' where last_name = 'jerry'
UPDATE EMP2_5
SET first_name = 'black' where last_name = 'snow'
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do it in a single query, although it would help if you had a unique identifier for each row.  For the given data, you can use any column:

```
update t
    set first_name = (case when last_name = 'snow' then 'black' else first_name end),
        dept_id = (case when last_name = 'jerry' then 50 else dept_id end)
    where last_name in ('jerry', 'snow');

commit;
```

However, two separate `update`s is much simpler, I think:

```
update t
    set first_name = 'black'
    where last_name = 'snow';

update t
    set dept_id = 50
    where last_name = 'jerry';

commit;
```

Comment: there has been missing keyword error for the single query

Comment: @gordon you missed `end` in first `case`